# Questionnaire suggestions for moderator elections

Tags: discussion, election

[An election is coming up soon](https://materials.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80/announcing-a-pro-tempore-moderator-election) to determine the first three moderators of this site.

Each candidate for the election will write a bit about themselves, and we can have an official list of questions that we would like each candidate to answer, in order to help us decide for whom we would like to vote.

There are some standard questions that are usually asked during elections:

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

For each answer to this post, please provide a question that you would like to see on the questionnaire. The votes on the answers will tell us which of them our users would most like to see in the final list.

Answer (score 8):

How do you feel about downvoting or closing questions by brand new users with a reputation of only 1 (and no experience on any Stack Exchange community), when the question is not spam or ill-intentioned, but of extremely low quality by Stack Exchange standards? Should their question be downvoted or closed immediately, or should comments be used to make suggestions to them for how to improve their question?

Comment: This question was used in a [recent questionnaire](https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com/q/160/3) for another SE election.

Answer (score 4):

What is your background in Matter Modeling? What credentials do you have in Matter Modeling that make you qualified to evaluate the quality of a question/answer, or to decide how on-topic a question might be, or whether further research should be required?

Answer (score 3):

Deleting comments is somewhat "permanent" in that no one can "vote" to un-delete them, and users cannot see comments ever again once they are deleted (even the author of the comments would no longer be able to see them). What would be your policy on deleting comments? Do you think funny comments should be deleted? Do you think that any unrelated comment should be deleted? In cases with no CoC violation, would you delete the comment yourself, or would you first ask the user to delete it themselves, so that they have a chance to save it if they wish? For how long would you wait for them to act, before you delete a comment yourself (if you do at all)?

Comment: This question was used in a [recent questionnaire](https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com/q/160/3) for another SE election.

Comment: There are 4 questions there :) (ok, you can delete my comment)

Comment: @I.Camps If you look at the Drones meta page where the question suggestions were made, I listed some of these separately, but then JNat combined them into 1 big question that contained multiple sub-questions. I've taken the question with multiple sub-questions, that was used in that election, and posted it here with a little bit changed.

Answer (score 3):

How much time per day do you have available to dedicate to this site?

Answer (score 2):

In your mind, what is the role of a moderator?

Comment: (Sorry for the off): The cause of the -16 (and of my suspension, too) is that I did not want to shut up. The same moderator gave me 1yr "leave" by whom you've complained. Probably this is why he did not react.

Answer (score 2):

As a moderator, would you tend to make your own decisions, or do you prefer to go with what the community wants? For example, would you delete a question that does not violate the CoC, without waiting for the community to vote for its deletion?

Answer (score 2):

As a moderator, how would you treat questions where there is a borderline consensus on whether it is on-topic or not? What would be your threshold for mod-hammering it closed?

(Question used in [another site](https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com/q/160))

Answer (score 2):

Much of the overall moderation done on the site, is done by the community itself, via the high-rep users that have the power to vote for closure/deletion/etc. As a moderator, you will be expected to be available to do the things that ordinary high-rep users  do *not* have the power to do, such as dealing with suspensions and flags. What is the longest time you would see yourself taking, to respond to a message from a 7-day suspended user, or for a fairly serious flag on a hot and highly popular question?

Answer (score 0):

If someone has a question about a moderator action or a question about the site in general, and the question is not considered "urgent" (for example having to do with a serious flag, harassment, user suspension, etc.), what is the longest it would take for you to be available to discuss the issue?

Answer (score 0):

What have you done for this site, that did not result in the possibility of reputation increase or progress towards badges, or increase in any visible stats (e.g. voting, editing, etc.)?